# mcmapply, accessing values in a data.frame and passing them to a function

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr

Im using **paralell** package and the function **mcmapply**

I have the folowing datastructure:

```
pfad <- structure(list(from.id = c(7018492265, 7535901036, 3332568326
    ), from.lon = c(11.8303853, 12.1840786, 12.014866), from.lat = c(48.1102703, 
    48.1140645, 47.8172942), to.id = c(7535901036, 3332568326, 130221481
    ), to.lon = c(12.1840786, 12.014866, 12.2078502), to.lat = c(48.1140645, 
    47.8172942, 47.8395169)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))


from.id                from.lon                from.lat      to.id                  to.lon                  to.lat
1 7018492265 11.83038529999999965980 48.11027030000000337395 7535901036 12.18407859999999942602 48.11406449999999779266
2 7535901036 12.18407859999999942602 48.11406449999999779266 3332568326 12.01486599999999960176 47.81729419999999919355
3 3332568326 12.01486599999999960176 47.81729419999999919355  130221481 12.20785019999999931883 47.83951689999999956626
```

and i would like to pass individual values to a function.
For example i would like to print out **from.id** out of every row of data.
I tried something like this:

```
  mcmapply(function(x) print(x[[1]]),pfad,mc.cores = n.cores)
```

But i get following output:

```
     from.id                    from.lon                    from.lat                       to.id 
7.018492265000000000000e+09 1.183038529999999965980e+01 4.811027030000000337395e+01 7.535901036000000000000e+09 
                     to.lon                      to.lat 
1.218407859999999942602e+01 4.811406449999999779266e+01
```

How can i access individual values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over each row, then you can do something like this:

```
parallel::mcmapply(
  FUN = function(x) {
    print(x[,"from.id"])
    },
  split(x = pfad, f = 1:nrow(pfad)),
  mc.cores = n.cores)
```

In your example, you looped over one data.frame on not its row. You could also do it like this:

```
parallel::mcmapply(function(x) print(x[[1]]),
                   list(pfad),
                   mc.cores = n.cores)
```

Here the loop is over a list of one, which is then given to your internal function.

Comment: I do now something similar. I create a nested list from pfad by   pfad <- setNames(split(pfad, seq(nrow(pfad))), rownames(pfad)) and then i use mclapply insead of mcmapply.